# Optimal optimization order

Tags: optimization, graph-theory

I am working on a system of optimisation problems. These tasks can be solved by a generic optimization accross all the state space. But some of my equations are independent of the remaining system( imagine a Jacobian Matrix with some blocks full of zero )  and i would like to use this fact to optimize first the joint equations and then taking the previous solution as an input finish to solve the independent components.
The rules that say the relation between the tasks can be represented as an oriented graph, but this graph contains cycle because of the joint equations, which mean that i can't use a topological sort on it.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this kind of pb?

Thx

Comment: I would need more detail to understand the problem. At any rate, graphs with cycles can be topologically sorted by treating the cycles as equivalence classes.

Comment: yes i totally agree with that. The question is to first compute the equivalence class and then maybe use a topolical sort. Do you know anywhere which use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of types of frameworks you can look into (instead of inventing it yourself), which might solve your problem. The question is a bit to abstract to tell which one suits your needs, so take a look at these:

1. Use a solver framework to solve this optimization and look through the search space of. Take a look at [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner.html), Gurobi, JGap, OpenTS, ...
2. Use a rules engine to apply the optimization changes. Take a look at [Drools Expert](http://www.jboss.org/drools), JESS, ...